# GWT Code Generation, MVC & Support

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm reading up on GWT and so far it sounds too good to be true (!).

I'd like to start investing the time to really learning GWT but I would have some very specific uses for it, and I'd hate to spend 2 weeks learning it only to find out that I can't use it after all.

I've combed over the FAQs and done a ton of searches but for the life of me cannot find answers to some very specific questions. Since they're so similar in nature (they all have to do with the capabilities of GWT, which are, surprisingly, largely-absent from the project docs) I figured rather than clutter SO with lots of micro-questions I would just put them here as they should shed light on the same issue that I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around:

- One of the hallmarked "best practices" for performant web development is to place CSS at the top of each HTML page, and JS at the bottom; **can GWT honor this**, and more generally, does GWT allow you to output client-side code however you like (meaning, the order the code gets generated in as well as the code that gets generated)?
- Does GWT support client-side MVC/MVP patterns? In a nutshell, how?
- Does GWT require any sort of special configuration, libraries, etc. for outputting a "mobile web" version of your code **in addition** to the "normal web" version (meaning, 2+ generated codebases where 1 is meant to be served to web browser and the other is meant to be served to a mobile browser like WebKit)?
- Where does the official GWT project (hosted and maintained by **Google**) document its list of supported browsers? I was only able to find [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_CurrentlySupportBrowsers) which is 4 years old.

Thanks in advance for any help/nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- GWT has many different boot mechanisms and is known to be very good about it. Take a look at different linkers if you like to know what you can do. In general its very good about this kind of things.
- There are good MVP Frameworks out there (GWTP - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) and there is also an MVP implementation inside GWT (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces)
- If you want to write mobile and desktop apps from the same code base take a look at m-gwt ( http://www.m-gwt.com), its a mobile framework that is built like the GWT Core.
- GWT Supports all relevant browsers since it is used by google very widely to power many google apps.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel (+1)! Just some quick followup questions: (1) What is the relationship between GWT and `m-gwt` - both Google projects? And (2) I am *sure* that GWT supports all relevant browsers (like you say) but I don't see that browser list anywhere in Google's GWT docs. Do you know where Google says (specifically) "*here is a list of all the browsers we support:...*"? I ask because in order to get business to approve my project I have to **prove** to them that all of their required browsers are supported by GWT. Thanks again!

Comment: I am part of the GWT Steering Committee which drives GWT. mgwt is my project and will hopefully become a standard for building mobile apps with GWT. On the browser thingy: I know there is something out there maybe we need to update it on the project site.